# Open(file) - Does it stay open?

Tags: python, file

I'm learning how to use `open(file, 'r')` and was wondering:

If I say `open(file1, 'r')`and then later try to access that same file using `open()` again, will it work? Because I never did `close()` on it. And does it close immediately after opening, because it's not assigned to any variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In cpython, if you use `open()` without assigning the result to a variable, the file is closed again immediately. On other python implementations (IronPython, jython, etc) this may not be the case; a file object in is closed when deleted by the garbage collector if not closed explicitly.

You can open files multiple times though, so you can always pass the same filename to `open()` again at a later time, file open or not.

It's usually best to use the open file as a context manager, by using a `with` statement. When the block of code indented under the `with` statement is done, the file automatically closed for you:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    # Do things with f

# f is automatically closed
```

Answer (score 1):

The file will stay open until you close it, or the Python process stops.  You can open it again, but you should close it when you are done.

The best way to do this is to use open as a with statement context manager:

```
with open("file", 'r') as f:
    # do stuff
```

Once the code leaves the with block, the file is automatically closed.  Actually, it's even better than that, because the file is closed even if the code leaves the block via an exception being raised. Of course, you can also just close the file using `file.close()`.

If you know that the file will not be too big, and all you want to do is read it, a common idiom is to just load the whole file into memory, and then you can forget about the file handle.  For example:

```
with open("file", 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()
```

To see if a file exists, use `os.path.exists`:

```
import os
os.path.exists("file")
```

Comment: No, the file remains open until the file object is garbage collected, which on cpython is immediately.

Comment: That's only if there are no references to it.

Comment: Exactly, which is what the OP is asking about. "because it's not assigned to any variable?"

Comment: Ah, missed that point.  Still, it's very bad style to rely on this CPython implementation detail (or to just use `open` without assignment in general).

Answer (score 1):

i don't know if i understood you well, but using open() you create object representing file stream. until you keep reference to this object, the file stream is opened. but if you call open() again for the same file, you'll make another object representing file stream. target of stream will be the sames but object's will be different.

i don't know how if garbage collector works in python the same as in java, but if it does, all the objects that are not pointed by any reference will be deleted from memory. not "immediately" but when garbage collector will run, and this is unpredictable. it may be now, and it may be in next few seconds.

Comment: The cpython garbage collector relies on reference counts. Not assigning the open file object means there are no references to it and it is collected immediately.